# WCF can't connect to an ASMX Web Service

Tags: wcf, service, asmx

I'm using WCF to connect to a remote web service (asmx) for testing at this point. The remote web service is unsecured for now (no https, no user name, password).  I can add the WCF service reference, and all the classes are generated ok.  When I make the call to the webservice, it just hangs.

So I can connect with the SOAP UI tool and return data just fine.  I'm thinking it is something wrong with my binding.  Anyone see anything I'm missing?

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <!-- Need to change some settings here for HTTPS and Basic Auth when those go online-->
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ServiceSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
            receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://<snip>/Service.asmx"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoap"
          contract="PRIOrderService.ServiceSoap" name="ServiceSoap" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: You're not bypassing the proxy, and the client request will assume your identity when it invokes the operation and it says to use the default proxy. The config file seems fine, only thing I can think of is the proxy, but that doesn't explain the plain "hang" (assuming you create a proxy instance)

Comment: is this document useful? http://nayyeri.net/integrating-wcf-clients-with-asmx-services

Comment: Thanks bnkdev and Rubens, so far no luck. I tried generating the proxy with the service util like the link above, and tried to connect, but still hangs. Must be some sort of a network issue. Bugs me that I can connect with SOAP-UI though.  Be nice if generated code actually worked as advertised ;)

Comment: Rubens, I used the srvutil and generated a service.cs and and output.config file (default names).  I ended up keeping the proxy that I generated by adding a service reference, but I did manage to munge the output.config file into my app.config file and got it working. If you post and answer, I'll mark you as the one who answered the question.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requesting the wsdl endpoint does not trigger a creation of the instance of your service. If you are using a custom service host factory look at that, otherwise look at the constructor of your service implementation or debug the service method itself.

Comment: Well, this was a junior varsity answer "check the basic stuff".  But Rubens Farias never came back, so you get the credit.  Regardless, I do appreciate the time you took to answer.